# Linq-To-SQL select, update and commit results in empty Table

Tags: linq-to-sql, select

Given:

```
using (DataContext ctx = new DataContext(props.ConnectionString))
{
    IQueryable<Email> emails = null;
    try
    {
       emails = ctx.Emails.Where(e => !(e.IsLocked || e.IsSent));
       foreach (var e in emails)
       {
           e.IsLocked = true;
       }
       ctx.SubmitChanges();
    }
}

// do something with emails here
```

Why is emails empty after SubmitChanges()? Is there any way to avoid emptying the Table after IsLocked is set to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table `ctx.Emails` is probably not empty. The collection `emails` is evaluated every time you call it.

You could do this if you want to keep the emails return on the initial call:

```
emails = ctx.Emails.Where(e => !(e.IsLocked || e.IsSent)).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't make sense, I can try to explain it better.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be. When I step through code and get past that point, opening emails in the locals window says "enumeration yielded no results".

Comment: The ToList() did work, though. So, does SubmitChanges() "purge" the Table? The foreach loop obviously resulted in the lazy load of all matching records...

Comment: Ok, let me explain it in more detail. `foreach (var e in emails)` is the first evaluation (thus going to the database). Then you update each email's `IsLocked` to true. `ctx.SubmitChanges();` updates each email's `IsLocked` to true in the database. if you then call the variable `emails`, the statement `ctx.Emails.Where(e => !(e.IsLocked || e.IsSent))` gets evaluated again (thus going to the database again), but then all the emails `IsLocked` are true, so it returns an empty collection.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas's answer is correct but I'll have a go at explaining it as well.

The `emails` collection is an enumeration that is reevaluated when you call it.  Picture it like this.

```
// another method...
IEnumerable<Email> GetEmails()
{
    return ctx.Emails.Where(e => !(e.IsLocked || e.IsSent));
}

// & inside your main method
foreach (var e in GetEmails())
{
    e.IsLocked = true;
}
ctx.SubmitChanges(); 

// now if you check the result it will be reevaluated
GetEmails();
```

This is intended behaviour.

If you want to 'get' the emails, do something to them and keep that collection, you should put them in a list / array. The enumeration isn't a real collection, it's more like a function that returns a collection when you query it.